# minhag of using beer motzai pesach

Tags: minhag, passover, havdalah, liquor-beer, nissan

I know some people who use beer for havdalah motzai pesach. It seems from halacha that wine should always be used even during the 9 days. Is there a source for the custom to use beer for havdalah motzai pesach?

Answer (score 2):

*Taame Haminhagim*, footnote 70 to section 597 (page 249), says:

> In the book *Maase Rav* of [the *gaon* of Vilna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon), of blessed memory, item 185, the author writes that [the Vilna *gaon*] tried, on the night after [*Pesach*], to taste *chametz*, and also did not eat, after *Pesach*, *matza* one could fulfill the obligation [of *matza*] with, in order to distinguish performance of the *mitzva*: that one does it not for pleasure but because of the decree of the creator. This implies that there's some *mitzva* in showing that we do not need to eat [as on *Pesach*] any further. I've also heard that [the rabbi of Sanz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanz), of blessed memory, said *havdala* after *Pesach* on beer.
>
> And in [*Minhagim*, by] [the *Maharil*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin), laws of *Pesach*, page 19, the author writes, "On the night after *Pesach*, there was no *chametz* in the house of [?], and they were unconcerned and ate *matza*". See there.

Comment: What is the relevance of the parts aside from the one-liner about the rabbi of Sanz?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the _G'ra_'s custom may be why people say _havdala_ on beer. The _Maharil_ story shows that even if viewed as preferable it's not necessary.

Comment: Sounds more like why people eat bread, noodles and cookies after havdala

Answer (score 1):

Found it thanks to [DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa). The Rama 296:2 writes that is a custom to use beer on motzai pesach. However, on a regular motzai Shabbas he writes that pagum (someone drank from it) wine is better than beer.

Comment: It interesting because in hilchos kiddush if one has wine only enough for one thing it should be used for havdallah.

Comment: here is a comment about it http://ohr.edu/5483#_edn16 but I'm missing something -- if beer is chomeitz, how does one have it to make havdalah over it?

Comment: @danno buy it from a non Jew.

Comment: @DoubleAA so say *hamavdil*, go out and buy beer, and only then make havdalah?

Comment: @Monica I guess so. I've only heard of one person that actually did this. I stick to my grape juice, thank you very much.

Comment: @DoubleAA monica asked my question -- am I waiting for an hour until my own beer (if I had sold it) might be bought back or am I going shopping while everyone else waits for me to come back.