Havdallah after Pesach
The Koren Machsor states that some have the custom to say Havdalah on beer after Pesach.

Any idea how this could be done as a practical matter?  Buy the beer before Pesach, sell it with your chametz, and then wait the extra hour or 2 for the chametz to be "repurchased" before you make Havdalah?  Buy the beer after Pesach before Havdalah?  Neither seems to be the practical basis for a minhag.

Anybody know of a source for the minhag?


thank you.

Possible duplicate (at least on part 2), see here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/minhag-of-using-beer-motzai-pesach

@Deuteronomy The Rav of town is meant to hurry and daven maariv and rush to buy back the chometz so that people don't eat from chametz before it's bought back. I don't have the source at hand but I've seen it done and that is my father's Minhag since he is the rav of his town and he sells the towns chametz

@Moishe how does that relate to what I've written?

@Deuteronomy in response to the 2 hour wait which generally doesn't exist because of the reason written above

@Moishe perhaps you've confused me with the OP. Once we're on the topic however it is worth pointing out that this custom predates the widespread reliance on the sale of hames.

The Rama mentions this custom (OC 296:2). Widespread instantaneous home chametz sales didn't exist back then so presumably the custom was to buy some beer from the local gentiles on the way home from synagogue. That's indeed how people I know who do this go about it.

I wonder how common it would have been to leave personal money in the synagogue before Y"T in anticipation of being able to participate in this custom afterwards. I also wonder whether anyone discusses the potential impediment this custom may precipitate (prompting people to carry and/or handle money on Y"T in anticipation of the post-Pesah purchase).

@Deuteronomy fair but plenty probably had tabs at local pubs.

@Deuteronomy another relevant custom could be extending barchu (even longer than general Saturday nights) traditionally explained as making sure no one jumped the gun to buy chametz too early. (Connecting these two motzaei pesach practices could well be anachronistic)

Good point... and interesting thought re: ברכו (anachronistic or not). Thanks for sharing :)

I'm told Chabad-Lubavitch is proud of the technique they use in selling chametz, so they purposely use bought-back beer to show it was a good sale.

Havdalah on Motzei Pesach at https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/havdalah-on-motzei-pesach/
states as follows:
Havdalah on Motzei Pesach:
The order of Havdalah follows the same order as any Motzei Yom Tov, or Motzei Shabbos if Yom Tov fell on Shabbos]. See Chapter 13 Halacha 11!
Beer:[1]  It is accustomed to be lenient to make Havdalah over beer on Motzei Pesach even if one has much wine at home available.[2] Nevertheless, if the beer is not currently beloved to the person, it is better to make Havdalah over wine even on Motzei Pesach. Furthermore, the above allowance only applies in those areas that beer is considered a significant drink. [The Chabad custom is not to make Havdalah on beer on Motzei Pesach.[3]]
{N.B.: The note in square brackets is in the original}

[1] Admur 296:10; Rama 296:2
[2] As at that time the beer is more beloved to a person than is wine. [ibid]
Other Opinions: Some Poskim rule based on Kabala that one is to always say Havdalah over wine rather than other beverages even if the beer is more beloved. [Kaf Hachaim 296:26]
[3] Otzer Minhagei Chabad Pesach p. 238
